# How to assert a line is logged using Monolog inside Symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit, monolog

I'm using Monolog inside Symfony2, using the default MonologBundle. I'm trying to assert inside my tests, that a line is logged. I've configured this in my `config_test.yml`:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:   test
            level:  debug
```

How do I get to the results of Monolog's `TestHandler` in my tests (that inherit from Symfony2's `WebTestCase`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As solution:

Get all handlers from `monolog` service and search test handler.

```
foreach ($this->container->get('monolog')->getHandlers() as $handler) {
  if ($handler instanceof TestHandler) {
    $testHandler = $handler;
    break;
  }
}

if (!$testHandler) {
  throw new \RuntimeException('Oops, not exist "test" handler in monolog.');
}

$this->assertFalse($testHandler->hasCritical()); // Or another assertions
```

Comment: Note that : This method is deprecated in Symfony 3.4 and will break in Symfony 4

Comment: Not sure about modern Symfony, but it works for Laravel 9 which uses Monolog 2 under the hood.

Comment: In new version of Symfony TestHandler can be retrieve with `self::getContainer()->get('monolog.handler.test')`

Answer (score 4):

In your command class, you have to simply set the handler with `pushHandler()`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class YourCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    // ...

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $logger = $this->getContainer()->get('logger');

        // PUSH THE OutputInterface OBJECT INTO MONOLOG
        $logger->pushHandler(new ConsoleHandler($output));

        // Your command logic here...
    }
```

In your test, using [`CommandTester`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#testing-commands):

```
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Command;

use AppBundle\Command\YourCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class YourCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $kernel = $this->createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        // mock the Kernel or create one depending on your needs
        $application = new Application($kernel);
        $application->add(new YourCommand());

        $command = $application->find('acme:your:command');

        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(
            array('command'   => $command->getName()),
            /**
             * Here set the verbosity
             */
            array('verbosity' => OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_DEBUG)
        );

        // die(print_r($commandTester->getDisplay()));

        $this->assertRegExp('/.../', $commandTester->getDisplay());
    }
}
```

**Keep attention to `array('verbosity' => OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_DEBUG)`.**

This way you'll can obtain all the logs (a INFO in this case, set with `$logger->info('Starting <info>acme:your:command</info>');`):

```
[2015-08-13 23:39:22] app.INFO: Starting acme:your:command:
```

Now you can use `$this->assertRegExp()`to check if a particular line is logged or not.

You can also transform the `string` in an `array` with

```
explode('\n', $commandTester->getDisplay())
```

This solution were [found here](https://www.webfactory.de/blog/symfony-2-4-use-log-messages-for-console-output) and is explained in the documentation of Monolog [here](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md#configuring-a-logger).

More about [Monolog and Symfony (Symfony Docu)](http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html).

More about [Monolog Handlers (Monolog Docu)](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#handlers).

## Symfony 5 (autowiring), PHP 7.4

```php
namespace App\Command;

use Monolog\Logger;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\ConsoleHandler;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class YourCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'acme:your:command';
    private LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        // PUSH THE OutputInterface OBJECT INTO MONOLOG
        if ($this->logger instanceof Logger) {
            $this->logger->pushHandler(new ConsoleHandler($output));
        }

        // Your command logic here...

        return self::SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

In your test, using [`CommandTester`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/console/console_command.html#testing-commands):

```php
namespace AppBundle\Tests\Command;

use AppBundle\Command\YourCommand;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;

class YourCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $application = new Application($kernel);

        $command = $application->find('acme:your:command');
        $commandTester = new CommandTester($command);
        $commandTester->execute(
            ['command'   => $command->getName()],
            /**
             * Here set the verbosity
             */
            ['verbosity' => OutputInterface::VERBOSITY_DEBUG]
        );

        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        // die(print_r($commandTester->getDisplay()));

        self::assertStringContainsString('/.../', $$output);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't trying to assert log lines in a command. A more generic, overall solution would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I don't understand what you would like to achieve... Can you update your question with some more details? Post the code of the test, so we can see how you implemented it and give you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question but giving my 2 cents.

Handlers are all registered as services, thus you can easily use dependency injection.

In <kbd>packages/test/monolog.yaml</kbd>

```
monolog:
  handlers:
    testing:
      type: test
      level: info
```

Then, in your test:

```
use Monolog\Handler\TestHandler;

// ...

private TestHandler $testHandler;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->testHandler = $this->get('monolog.handler.testing');
}

public function testSomething()
{
    // ...

    // Get records
    $this->testHandler->getRecords();
}
```

If you have a base class for your tests, you can create a helper:

```
protected function assertIsLogged(string $partOfMessage, int $level = Logger::DEBUG): void
{
    /** @var TestHandler $handler */
    $handler = $this->get('monolog.handler.testing');

    foreach ($handler->getRecords() as $record) {
        // Ignore logs below expected level
        if ($record['level'] < $level) {
            continue;
        }

        if (\str_contains($record['message'], $partOfMessage)) {
            $this->addToAssertionCount(1);

            return;
        }
    }

    $this->fail(sprintf('Failed to assert that a log contains "%s" for minimum level %s.', $partOfMessage, Logger::getLevelName($level)));
}
```